# SVG rotation cuts off the edge

Tags: svg, rotation

I am trying to rotate a SVG on a T-Shirt designer project but edges of the SVG are getting cut off. The code for the SVG is as follows:

**Before Rotation (Everything is correct in this)**

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="scale(2,2)rotate(0,50,50)" id="clip1">
    <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100px" width="100px" y="0px" x="0px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1">
    <g>
    [POLYGON CODE WAS HERE]
    </svg>
</g>
```

**After Rotation (One of the edges is getting cut off!!!)**

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="scale(2,2)rotate(45,50,50)" id="clip1">
    <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100px" width="100px" y="0px" x="0px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1">
    <g>
    [POLYGON CODE WAS HERE]
    </svg>
</g>
```

Everything in the above 2 codes is the same except for the rotate(...) function.

The screenshot of what is going wrong can be found here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCyou.png. In the right side image, the elbow is cut off as well as the background behind that. The SVG file code is present here - http://pastebin.com/LfC7TkwV

Is this the default behavior of SVG rotation or am I missing some other tag to make this work? Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely due to viewport clipping from the rootmost svg element. Verify that the root svg has a width/height that is big enough to contain the rotated parts completely.

Answer (score 1):

As Erik says, the rotate operation is causing part of the design to fall outside the viewport.  You may have to add a small translate() to your transform, and/or enlarge the size of your `viewBox` so that it encompasses the new larger bounding box.